# Onclick on document and not specific element Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML here

```js
$(document).click(function(){
    alert('Document Clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button type='button'>CLICK [NO ALERT]</button>
    <button type='button'>ME[NO ALERT]</button>
</body>
```

In my code here, How do I prevent the alert from showing up if I clicked on the buttons, But anything except the buttons can be alerted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add another `click` listener on that specific `<button>` and stop the propagation of the event:

```js
$(document).click(function(){
  alert('Document Clicked');
})
$('.not-clickable').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button type='button'>CLICK [NO ALERT]</button>
    <button type='button' class="not-clickable">ME[NO ALERT]</button>
</body>
```

**Another option** is to check if the element that was clicked is that specific button:

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
  if (e.target.classList.contains('not-clickable')) {
    return;
  }
  alert('Document Clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button type='button'>CLICK [NO ALERT]</button>
    <button type='button' class="not-clickable">ME[NO ALERT]</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I add another example, I hope if you can check it too, Since it will only use the 2nd option you used only, Just to calrify the difference

Comment: I don't really understand your update. If you want to alert only the click on the `button` just remove the first `$(document).click...`

Comment: Never mind me, You're right, Just realized it was just another repeated addition

Answer (score 0):

try it

```html
$("#SomeElementId").click(function(e) {
   //do something
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it `<button type='button' onclick="event.stopPropagation()">CLICK [NO ALERT]</button>`.
By default click events are fired to parent element, but event.stopPropagation(), keeps it only the element origin of event.